# Training a FF Neural Language Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, language-model

Consider 3-grams of the sentence "The cat is upstairs" where each word is separated by the rest with @ and ~ symbols.

```
trigrams = ['@th', 'the', 'he~', '@ca', 'cat', 'at~', '@is', 'is~', 
             '@up', 'ups', 'pst', 'sta', 'tai', 'air', 'irs', 'rs~']
```

I want to train a character based Feed Forward Neural Language model using this sentence, but I am having trouble fitting the X and y parameters correctly.

My code is as follows :

```
# trigrams encoded
d = dict([(y,x+1) for x,y in enumerate(sorted(set(trigrams)))])
trigrams_encoded = [d[x] for x in trigrams]
# trigrams_encoded = [3, 15, 8, 1, 7, 6, 2, 10, 4, 16, 11, 13, 14, 5, 9, 12]

# x_train
x_train = [] # list of lists, each list contains 3 encoded trigrams
for i in range(len(trigrams_encoded)-3) :
    lst = trigrams_encoded[i:i+3]
    x_train.append(lst)
x_train = np.array(x_train)            # x_train shape is (13,3)

# y_train
y_train = trigrams_encoded[3:]
data = np.array(y_train)
y_onehot = to_categorical(data)        # y_onehot shape is (13,17)
y_onehot = np.delete(y_onehot, 0, 1)   # now shape is (13,16)

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(d), 10, input_length=3)) #len(d) = 16
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(d), activation='softmax'))

# compile the model
# i have set sparse_categorical_crossentropy here, but not sure if this is correct. feel free to change it
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_onehot, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

My initial attempt was to say that since input_length=3, the model will take as input triplets of the listed n-grams which should be labelled as the next n-gram in the list. But this seems to fail. (should it fail ?)

The above code raises the following error which I do not know how to solve :

```
"InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup' defined at (most recent call last):

(... many lines...)

Node: 'sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup'
indices[5,1] = 16 is not in [0, 16)"
```

Could you please assist on the correct choices of X and y here ?

Comment: Could you share how you create `X`? You are correct that the inputs should be triplets of trigrams, but they must be integer-encoded.

Comment: @eschibli .. thank you for your reply.. kindly see my edited post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine when using `categorical_crossentropy` as your loss function, since you are using one-hot encoded labels:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

trigrams = ['@th', 'the', 'he~', '@ca', 'cat', 'at~', '@is', 'is~', 
             '@up', 'ups', 'pst', 'sta', 'tai', 'air', 'irs', 'rs~']


# trigrams encoded
d = dict([(y,x+1) for x,y in enumerate(sorted(set(trigrams)))])
trigrams_encoded = [d[x] for x in trigrams]
# trigrams_encoded = [3, 15, 8, 1, 7, 6, 2, 10, 4, 16, 11, 13, 14, 5, 9, 12]

# x_train
x_train = [] # list of lists, each list contains 3 encoded trigrams
for i in range(len(trigrams_encoded)-3) :
    lst = trigrams_encoded[i:i+3]
    x_train.append(lst)
x_train = np.array(x_train)            # x_train shape is (13,3)

# y_train
y_train = trigrams_encoded[3:]
data = np.array(y_train)
y_onehot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(data)        # y_onehot shape is (13,17)
y_onehot = np.delete(y_onehot, 0, 1)   # now shape is (13,16)

# define model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(d) + 1, 10, input_length=3)) #len(d) = 16
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(d), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_onehot, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```

`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` only works with sparse integer values.

Comment: No it doesn't.. It gives the same "InvalidArgumentError: ... etc... " error as the one I describe in my post..

Comment: Can you maybe explain what you mean a bit more?  @john_ny

Comment: I deleted my above comment to better rephrase the question.. So, after the model is trained we will have to validate it on unseen samples. A sample point will be a triplet of 3-grams, which in order to fit to the model (for the prediction part) will have to take the form of a triplet of integers.. How can I compute this integers though? If a test 3-gram is already seen by the model during training.. I can assign to that one of the integers included in d dictionary (see code above).. but if the test 3gram is unknown to the model then how can i choose its new integer description ?

Comment: @john_ny the test 3-gram cannot be assigned arbitrary integer values, because your embedding layer only knows how to map integer values from 0 to 16 to their vector representations.

Comment: Or am I missing something?

Comment: So if I understand correctly passing the train 3-grams via integer encodings prevents the model from making predictions ? My question in other words is the following : if one of the test 3-grams is 'dog' and observing that dog is not contained in the training 3-grams, what is its integer representation in order to fit to the model ? I understand that I cannot use one of the 16 integers already defined via training.. (Thank you for helping)

Comment: @john_ny you should have an integer that represents "out of vocabulary"

Comment: @eschibli Yes, it is the integer zero in this example. The others are taken by the trigrams..